# Could Monero implement zk-SNARKS in the future?

Tags: ring-signatures, zcash, zk-snarks

At the moment ring signatures are more eficient than zk-SNARKS, but as fluffypony already comment, probably any cryptocurrencie in the future will use this technology. Can monero implement zk-SNARKS in the future if needed?
How can it be done?

Comment: Can you link to the fluffypony comment you cited (clarifying "efficient") if it is a necessary component of your question?

Answer (score 1):

Riccardo has mentioned that zk-SNARKs could be used in temporary sidechains. There is no official plan laid out yet to my knowledge.

Comment: Did he mention zk-SNARKs or zk-STARKs (no trusted setup)?

Answer (score 0):

Why? I don't think it make sense to do with the main chain at all.

I could be wrong but I think to begin those types of ‘shielded’ transactions you first have to perform a type of trusted setup where a key becomes split into shards.  This seems silly to me...even if they find a way to do it without an initial trusted key; it seems pointless for Monero at the moment where its own privacy methods seem adequate.

In the future... maybe ... but, again, why?